# How do I plot a contour from a table of values?

Tags: matplotlib, pytorch, contour, contourf

I have a table that has 2 features `(x,y)` - and a vector with the same length that contains their corresponding values `(z)`.

I'm trying to use matplotlib to print this as a 2D plot but I am get an error:

`TypeError: Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, but has shape (5797, 1)`

Is there any way to solve this? (since I am trying to use 1d arrays instead of 2d arrays)

The relevant code:

```
x, y = train_features[:,0], train_features[:,1]
z = train_predictions.detach()
print(x.size())
print(y.size())
print(z.size())

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x, y, z)
CS = plt.contourf(x, y, z)
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=8, colors='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)
```

The prints that result from the prints commands:

```
torch.Size([5797])
torch.Size([5797])
torch.Size([5797, 1])
```

EDIT:
I tried to implement this with a second method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

npts = 200
ngridx = 100
ngridy = 200
x = train_features[:,0]
y = train_features[:,1]
z = train_predictions.detach().squeeze()


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# -----------------------
# Interpolation on a grid
# -----------------------
# A contour plot of irregularly spaced data coordinates
# via interpolation on a grid.

# Create grid values first.
xi = np.linspace(1, 10, ngridx)
yi = np.linspace(1, 10, ngridy)

# Perform linear interpolation of the data (x,y)
# on a grid defined by (xi,yi)
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z)
Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = interpolator(Xi, Yi)

ax1.contour(xi, yi, zi, levels=100, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
cntr1 = ax1.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=14, cmap="RdBu_r")

fig.colorbar(cntr1, ax=ax1)
ax1.plot(x, y, 'ko', ms=3)
ax1.set_title('grid and contour (%d points, %d grid points)' %
              (npts, ngridx * ngridy))
```

But the resulting image was the following:

[image]

even though z's values are:

`tensor([-0.2434, -0.2155, -0.1900,  ..., 64.7516, 65.2064, 65.6612])`

Comment: contour requires gridded data. There are different ways to visualize if you don't have gridded data, for example https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html

Comment: I tried to implement it using the link you suggest but I'm still running into problems - see edit in original post

Comment: Looks like all the points are covering the plot. Remove the `ax1.plot(x, y, 'ko', ms=3)` line and see if it looks better.

Comment: Thanks! The plot does appear now. However, it only fills the left side of the plot, which makes sense since the values of the x-axis feature range from 1 to 7, but is there a way to use interpolation to fill the right part as well?

Comment: To extend the plot you would need to perform extrapolation, not interpolation. There are lots of ways to extrapolate but likely any naive or general extrapolation won't look very good.